# Portable C++ stream redirection of child processes

Tags: c++, command-line-interface, io-redirection

I'm looking for a platform-agnostic (*nix, Windows, OSX) way to programmatically interact with child processes that are command line interfaces. The calling program is also a console application (relevant on Windows). The input/output/possibly error streams should be readable/writable by the parent process. I don't mind an implementation that has platform-specific code so long as it has an implementation for each common platform. For comparison: Python's [popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

Comment: I think you should look at ACE (http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html). Specifically: `ACE_Process_Manager`, `ACE_Pipe`, `ACE_Process` classes

Comment: In what ways is ACE better than, say, http://libexecstream.sourceforge.net/ ? (from the duplicate question)

Comment: Although I have never compared them before, I can say from a quick look at the home page of `libexecstream` that it has almost no features comparing to ACE. Especially, the page says `Works on Linux and Windows` when the OP specifically mentioned OS X